# RabbitMQ topic binding, do they have a priority?

Tags: rabbitmq

In [RabbitMQ Fifth Tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-ruby.html) (for Ruby, but they're the same for all languages), they mention:

> We created three bindings: Q1 is bound with binding key "`*.orange.*`"
>   and Q2 with "`*.*.rabbit`" and "`lazy.#`"

and then:

> "`lazy.pink.rabbit`" will be delivered to the second queue only once,
>   even though it matches two bindings.

How is this possible? For all I know, if a routing key matches 45 queues, it will go to all 45 queues. Why isn't this the case here as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Q2` has two bindings that both will match single message. According to
[AMQP 0.9.1 specification, section 1.7.2.3. Method queue.bind](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp-xml-doc0-9-1.pdf) (page 35):

> A server MUST not deliver the same message more than once to a queue, even if the queue has multiple bindings that match the message.
>
> **Test scenario**:
>
> A client declares a named queue and binds it using multiple bindings to the
>   `amq.topic` exchange. The client then publishes a message that matches all its bindings.

so while `lazy.pink.rabbit` routing key matches both `*.*.rabbit` and `lazy.#` routing keys, the message won't be duplicated to `Q2` and only one copy of that message will reside in `Q2`.

*P.S.:*

There are nice [Compatibility and Conformance](https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html) RabbitMQ documentation page, which contains all specs in one place.

Comment: As a detail, internally RabbitMQ takes care of removing duplicates from the list of queues that match a certain routing key,

Comment: didn't notice there was a same queue matching the same pattern. Thanks.